# Generating token in Stripe on server Side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, stripe-payments

I want to create some tests to check my subscription failed processus.

At first I use a good working card (42...) and subscribe then I want to update the card of the Stripe Customer with the bad working card (40...4) to check the code of my webhook in case of failed subscription.

The problem I encounter, is to update a customer card, I should have a token, but my tests are written only server side (no javascript).

Is there any way to generate a token from server-side with Stripe?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token

Comment: Wow thanks you, I look at the documentation but never landed on this part!

Comment: Maybe this: https://market.mashape.com/noodlio/noodlio-pay-smooth-payments-with-stripe